# ssis package that grab sql data and ftp it using 4 text files

Tags: ssis, ftp-client

I need to create a package that would upload 4 files on the ftp server and 4 files with some specification about the rowcount, process date....I wonder how would i go around this. I have tested with creating and ftp one text file and everything ok, but i am not sure how do i go with create 4. do i create 4 separate data flows or in the same dataflow. If in the same dataflow, could i use same ole db source connection considering all 4 text files are uploaded from same data source - sql server. I am very new at this and I am not sure if the ftp could be done using foreach and the data flow task in the foreach ftp task. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

in theory you can. You can use variables as the file names. Check for dynamic file connections. Ine exemple [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1084/dynamic-flat-file-connections-in-sql-server-integration-services/)

Comment: I have done the connection. Thank you. Now I need for each file to write some info in another text file. Help is apreciated. I was thinking to use input/output variable that i already have, but not sure how to write them to a text file.